# how to store database offline and share to server when online?

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, local-storage, offline

Could someone recommend simple method or service for this?

Basically we have an iPad app but it should be able to store form data also when offline. So I'd need a local storage and sync it to server when it's back online.

We need to be able to handle few thousand form inputs and javascript/html is heavily preferred in this case.

Many thanks gurus

Comment: So ... What have you already tried?

Comment: Please, do some research. This is not a "we happily do your research instead of you" site. Come back when you have specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Save it using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage):

```
localStorage.setItem('whatever', value);
```

Whenever you're back online, just retrieve it using:

```
localStorage.getItem('whatever');
```